# New Line in TWIG Form (Prestashop HelpBox)

Tags: html, symfony, twig, prestashop

I'm having small problem on modifying `Prestashop Forms` which works with `Symfony TWIG` Forms as from v.17 upward.

I would like to have a new line inside the help box, this is the code I use to try create new line.

```
<span class="help-box" data-toggle="popover"
    data-content="                              
    {{ "Please key-in either one of %, $ or # for the discount type of the 
        reward:
    <br />
    % - Discount in Percentage
    $ - Discount in USD"|trans({}, 'Admin.Catalog.Help')
    }}" >
</span>
```

Instead I got this result:

[image]

As seen here, the formatting will be treated as normal text, not special `NewLine Character`

Is there a way to treat all of the string became raw, so that new line can be achieved?

Thank You for the time.

Comment: Should work as is. Make sure it not the popup's `javascript` that is interfering with your output.

Comment: `{{ "I like Twig.\nYou will like it too."|trans({}, 'Admin.Catalog.Help')|nl2br }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the popover must be indicated you will use HTML code with `data-html="true"`, this code should works:

```
<span class="help-box" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true"
    data-content="                              
    {{ "Please key-in either one of %, $ or # for the discount type of the 
        reward:
    <br />
    % - Discount in Percentage
    $ - Discount in USD"|trans({}, 'Admin.Catalog.Help')
    }}" >
</span>
```

[You can see more info about popover in the official documentation of Bootstrap 4.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/)

Comment: thanks @Rolige it works and able to create new line in the help box